# Find which characters were changed in strings and where they were changed

Tags: r, string

Using the dataframe below as an example, supposed I only have the first two columns of text. How would I generate the `new_` columns, where I find *what* changed and *where* it changed? (A solution using base R is preferred.)

```
library(tidyverse)

df <- tibble(current_text = c('thank','thanks','thank','thdank'),
             previous_text = c(NA, 'thank','thanks','thank'),
             new_text = c(NA, 's','[DELETE]','d'),
             new_text_position = c(NA, 6, NA, 3)
             )
```

Comment: This is possible, but I'm not sure how well specified your expected output is. Going from NA to "thank" seems to result in NA rather than showing the addition of the fragment "thank", since the second and fourth  elements seem to return the letter that was added. Also, your third entry doesn't specify which character(s) were deleted. Also, in real text it seems likely you will have some strings that have multiple fragments changed. How should these be represented?

Comment: `?adist` is probably the only thing that will get you close in base R, which is capable of returning strings of `M`atch, `I`nsert, and `S`ubstitution for Levenshtein edit distances - e.g. `dm <- attr(adist(df$current_text, counts=TRUE), "trafos"); c(NA, dm[(row(dm)-col(dm))==1])`

Comment: Thanks for these, I need to respecify this. Basically I have a before-text and after-text, and am trying to figure out which keystroke was entered. If it's more than one keystroke, I throw it out anyway. So I need to find which 1 character was added/deleted, and where.